# How do I redirect to a URL using data from a form input?

Tags: html, django

I'm trying to request a number from the user and redirect to a page

website.com/players/number

I'm unsure of how to do that

I tried the below

```
<form action =  "/players/{content}" method = "post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type ="text" name ="content"/>
    <input type ="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

It doesn't really do anything. I'm unsure how to do this. thanks

Comment: Did you mean, `{content}` is coming from `<input name="content"` and then redirect as what was user input?

Comment: Yeah. For example in the form if the user enters 3439123, I want it to go to the webpage website.com/players/3439123

Comment: you must create a view, send parameter to it, search in DB with 'get_object_or_404' method, redirect to template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly. You can submit to a generic URL and then redirect:

```
<form action="/submit-and-redirect/" method="post">
```

```
def submit_and_redirect(request):
    content = request.POST.get('content')
    return redirect('/players/{}/'.format(content))
```

or you could use JS - for example jQuery:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = '/players/' + $('input[name=content]').val() + '/';
});
```

Comment: How is it getting the content of the users response from the previous page?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How is which getting the response from where?

Comment: [http://puu.sh/DJH1x/0ff55b5a91.png]

Here is what my template page displays. I want the user to input their ID and upon clicking search, redirect to the webpage /players/the_id_they_just_inputted.

I don't see how  ```content = request.POST.get('content')``` solves this issue.

Comment: How does it not? That is the value of your content field. Which is then used to create the URL to redirect to.

Comment: ah, I see it. I wasn't sure if the content field only stayed there within the template and didnt carry over to the views.